# magento homepage can be accessed both by http and https

Tags: magento, https

I'm trying to setup Let's encrypt SSL for a Magento website at

https://turbofun.no/

It shows SSL correctly. However, the problem is if i access it using

http://turbofun.no/

It shows normal page without https. I think it should automatically redirect viewer to https because it is homepage.

I read some topics about adding rewrite rules to redirect all http to https but i just want to use https on homepage, checkoutpage, customer login page.

Do you know what i missed in configuration? Thank you

Comment: for my knowledge for home page https is not required according to google team. for checkout and login pages , please check it : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6341/secure-checkout-and-login-page-online

Comment: even it is not required, i think Magento should always use homepage in HTTPS mode. It acts like that on my other projects.  This one is a project with virtualmin, debian, let's encrypt.  Do you know apache rewrite rule for only homepage http to https? not all pages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?